# iTextSharp - Tabela dinamica

Tags: c#, .net, itextsharp

Estou a tentar via C# e com o iTextSharp criar um doc pdf com a seguinte estrutura:
Tenho uma tabela com 3 Rows
Na 1ª tenho X colunas com X anos.
Na 2ª uma Row com os Meses (J, F, M...etc) por cada ano, abaixo tenho outra Row que quero afetar a propriedade da celula deBackgroundColor para qualquer coisa,

Estou a ter muitas dificultades em faze-lo, será que alguém me ajuda por aqui?
Eis parte do código, já mexi e remexi tanto que vou refazer de novo.

```
        PdfPTable tabelaAnos = new PdfPTable(iAnos);         
        for (int i = 0; i < iAnos; i++)
        {
            PdfPCell cellAnos1 = new PdfPCell();
            AnoInicio = AnoInicio + 1;
            cellAnos1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Ano " + AnoInicio));
            cellAnos1.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
            tabelaAnos.AddCell(cellAnos1);
        }

       for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
       {
           PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
           cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Meses com  " + i + " columns"));
           cell.Colspan = 12;
           cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1; //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
          tabelaAnos.AddCell(cell);   
        }
```

[image: Tabela que quero criar]

Comment: O procedimento é criar uma tabela com anos*meses colunas e usar colspan 12 no primeiro row na coluna 1, 13, etc.

Comment: Sim já o tentei, mas na teoria é mto simples, já criei dezenas de tabelas em html e em aspnet, mas o iText não se comporta como queremos.

Comment: Hoje à noite preparo um exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado Paulo, mas entretanto resolvi a questão depois de muito penar.

Eis a solução que encontrei.
Obrigado pela sua ajuda.

```
public static PdfPTable DRDRCriaTabelaCronogramaPDF(DataRow dr, iTextSharp.text.Font FontLinha)
       {
           PdfPTable tabelaCronograma = null;
           int NumAnos = Convert.ToInt16(dr["PeriodoAnosDiff"]);
           int AnoInt = Convert.ToInt16(dr["AnoInicio"]);

           tabelaCronograma = new PdfPTable(NumAnos * 12);
           tabelaCronograma.WidthPercentage = 100;
           PdfPCell CellMaster = new PdfPCell();
           for (int i = 0; i < NumAnos; i++)
           {
               CellMaster = new PdfPCell(new Phrase((AnoInt++).ToString(), FontLinha));
               CellMaster.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
               CellMaster.Colspan = 12;
               tabelaCronograma.AddCell(CellMaster);
           }
           CellMaster = new PdfPCell();
           int Mes = 1;
           for (int i = 0; i < NumAnos * 12; i++)
           {
               CellMaster = new PdfPCell(new Phrase((GeneralFuncs.DRDRRetornaLetraMes((Mes++).ToString())), FontLinha));
               tabelaCronograma.AddCell(CellMaster);
               if (Mes == 13)
                   Mes = 1;
           }

           Mes = 1;
           int MesInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DataInicioAcao"]).Month;
           int MesFim = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DataFimAcao"]).Month;

           int AnoInicio = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DataInicioAcao"]).Year;
           int AnoFim = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DataFimAcao"]).Year;

           int AnoInicioProj = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DataInicio"]).Year;
           int AnoFimProj = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DataFim"]).Year;

           int IndiceMesInicio = Convert.ToInt16(dr["IndiceMesInicio"]);
           int MesesDeDuracao = Convert.ToInt16(dr["MesesDiff"]);

           for (int i = 0; i < NumAnos * 12; i++)
           {
               if (Mes >= IndiceMesInicio && Mes <= IndiceMesInicio + MesesDeDuracao - 1)
               {
                   CellMaster = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                   CellMaster.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(0, 150, 0);
                   tabelaCronograma.AddCell(CellMaster);
               }
               else
               {
                   CellMaster = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
                   CellMaster.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(255, 255, 255);
                   tabelaCronograma.AddCell(CellMaster);
               }
               Mes++;
           }

           return tabelaCronograma;
       }
```

[image: Imagem final do cronograma]

Answer (score 0):

boa tarde aqui segue a minha tabela dinâmica com imagens.

```
       PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "));
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Produtos"));
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Quantidade"));
        table.AddCell(cell);

        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Preco"));
        table.AddCell(cell);          
        

        foreach (var item in detalhes_do_pedido)
        {                         
            Image fotos = Image.GetInstance(@"C:\imagens\" + item.Produto.ImagemUrl);
            ViewBag.foto = fotos;
            fotos.ScaleAbsolute(70, 70);
            table.AddCell(fotos);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.Produto.Nome));
            table.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.Quantidade.ToString()));
            table.AddCell(cell);

            cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(item.Produto.Preco.ToString()));
            table.AddCell(cell);
        }

        document.Add(table);
```